# dynamic return type of a function

Tags: c#

How can I create a function that will have a dynamic return type based on the parameter type?

Like

```
protected DynamicType Test(DynamicType type)
{

return ; 

}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'd have to use generics for this. For example,

```
protected T Test<T>(T parameter)
{

}
```

In this example, the '`<T>`' tells the compiler that it represents the name of a type, but you don't know what that is in the context of creating this function. So you'd end up calling it like...

```
int foo;

int bar = Test<int>(foo);
```

Comment: What if T is a type in an external assembly and is only accessible as `Type type` using reflection? `Test<type>` won't work obviously.

Answer (score 32):

Whilst the accepted answer is good, it has been over two years since it was written, so, I should add that you can use:

```
protected dynamic methodname(dynamic input)
{
    return input;
}
```

Input will be returned as the same type, and you do not need to call the method as a generic.

**Reference:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: It's also worth noting that the accepted answer can also use generic type inference, allowing you to call it as `Test(foo)` and not have to specify the generic argument explicitly.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Thanks... Generics are not my strong point (yet!) and I am still learning - Was about to write a question about Dynamic functions and saw this in the suggested list... Just though I should add it!

Comment: Thank you both for the Input, each has it is own use as i see

Comment: Did you mean `Dynamic` or the [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) keyword?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. What could be the repercussions of using all my methods with `dynamic`  keyword?

Comment: @Mwas I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but primarily the biggest drawback to dynamic is just that you lose intellisense and many errors that could have been caught at compile time will now not show up until the run the application.

Answer (score 6):

Actually,  assuming that you have a known set of parameters and return types, it could be handled with simple overloading:

```
protected int Test(string p) {   ...  }
protected string Test(DateTime p ) { .... }
```

Comment: The issue here is what if the caller does not know the type before calling. Eg only one of string or int is valid not both.

Comment: @rolls - Of course he does.  He's passing a variable (or constant) of a certain type to the method.  He's putting the return value into a variable of a certain type.   He clearly wants to use the same method in different places with different types.

Comment: Yes in this example. I was more talking generally.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need use generics.

```
protected T Test(T type) {

return type;

}
```

Comment: @Shiko, actually if you look at the timestamp, this came before Adam's answer.

Comment: @uchamp my bad, I will remove my comment

Answer (score 1):

C# is not a dynamic language. To tackle this problem in C# you can return a generic object and typecast later to whatever you think the value should be -- not recommended. You can also return an interface, this way you don't really care about a specific class instance. As others have pointed out you can also use generics. It really depends on what you need / want to do inside the body of the function since all the methods above have their own limitations.

Comment: C# is now dynamic if you want it to be. Use the 'dynamic' type.