# Dynamic SQL binding with MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, model-binding

In the following code, I know that query output is mapped with class SOURCE. UNLIKE this, I have a SQL[this query is not fixed], So query output is different[different column names and types, and number of columns]. How can I make a model on the fly as my query is not fixed?

```
public IEnumerable<SOURCE> get_all_sources()
{
            string _sql = "select column1,column2 from source";
            var q = __context.Database.SqlQuery<SOURCE>(_sql);
            return q.ToList();
}
```

eg: first time : query result : column1, column2, column3, second time it might be only one column, column1. I want to build a model to grab query output on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the data (eg JSON) and return serialized as string to deserialize on the other end (wherever this ends up).

If the return trypes are similar enough, you could have them all inherit from the same superclass.

You could use generics (see: [dynamic return type of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744401/dynamic-return-type-of-a-function))